# Incorrect / redundant where clause

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I'm not the best a Linq and I have written the below query and it just seems my where clause is redundant and there has to be a better way?

Given the following XML structure:

```
<Views>
  <Fulfillment>
    <SecurityRoleName>ABCD</SecurityRoleName>
      <SecurityRoleViews>
        <RoleView name="A" />
        <RoleView name="B" />
        <RoleView name="C" />
        <RoleView name="D" />
        <RoleView name="E" />
        <RoleView name="F" />
      </SecurityRoleViews>
      <PublicRoleViews>
        <RoleView name="Z" />
        <RoleView name="Y" />
        <RoleView name="X" />
        <RoleView name="W" />
        <RoleView name="V" />
        <RoleView name="U" />
      </PublicRoleViews>
    </Fulfillment>
</Views>
```

I wrote the following to get a single value (FulfillmentRoleName) and two List (SecuredViews, PublicViews) objects.

```
FulfillmentRoleName = configParms.Descendants("Fulfillment")
                                    .Where(node => (string)node.Element("SecurityRoleName") == "SecurityRoleName")
                                    .Select(node => node.Value.ToString())
                                    .First();


SecuredViews = configParms.Descendants("SecurityRoleViews")
                            .Where(node => (string)node.Element("RoleView") == "RoleView")
                            .Select(node => node.Attribute("name").Value.ToString())
                            .ToList();


PublicViews = configParms.Descendants("PublicRoleViews")
                            .Where(node => (string)node.Element("RoleView") == "RoleView")
                            .Select(node => node.Attribute("name").Value.ToString())
                            .ToList();
```

I would want the following values:

FulfillmentRoleName = ABCD

SecuredViews = List of names A,B,C...

PublicViews  = List of names Z,Y,X....

It is the where clause that I am unsure of:

```
.Where(node => (string)node.Element("RoleView") == "RoleView")
```

Seems there has to be a more elegant way to locate that node?

Thank you for taking the time to help

---

As per Ahmad Mageed recommendation I am using the more elegant Element("") approach. However I am getting an instantiation error...as if the element collection is not built yet??

[image]

However if I use configParms.Root.Value I get my SecurityRoleName value???

I would have thought that views would be the root....or is it the first node that has a value???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Elements` method and provide the name to match. This would allow you to replace the where query with `Elements("RoleView")`.

Some other observations:

- You can simplify the first query by grabbing the "Fulfillment" element directly by using the `Element` method, instead of `Descendants`.
- The `Value` property returns a string. The `ToString()` calls are redundant.

Here's an updated version of your queries:

```
// if configParms is an XDocument use configParms.Root
var securityRoleName = configParms.Element("Fulfillment")
                                  .Element("SecurityRoleName").Value;

var securedViews = configParms.Descendants("SecurityRoleViews")
                            .Elements("RoleView")
                            .Select(node => node.Attribute("name").Value)
                            .ToList();

var publicViews = configParms.Descendants("PublicRoleViews")
                            .Elements("RoleView")
                            .Select(node => node.Attribute("name").Value)
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: The two List queries make sense and are exactly what I was after. Thank You! One question regarding the first query. Do I have to walk down the node tree from Fulfillment to SecurityRoleName etc. I assume so because you probably would have just jumped to it in your example......configParms.Element("SecurityRoleName").Value

Comment: @user1278561 Yes, by using `Element` I'm walking down from the root, to Fulfillment, then again to SecurityRoleName. `Descendants("SecurityRoleName")` would let you grab all nodes of that name without walking the nodes, but it returns an `IEnumerable` which would result in a longer query with `First`/`Single` at the end (similar to what you originally had). Since it is indeed one element, the `Element` approach is clearer and more direct.

Comment: @user1278561 The error you mentioned will happen when using an XDocument instead of an XElement and you'll need to use the Root property. The first query should use configParms.Root.Element(...). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675196.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.root(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ahhh now I understand your //comment in the code sample provided...thanks again for your patience.